# How to get subsequent keys from a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

so I'm working on this referencing problem in which I need to get a key from a dictionary and its child keys(if any)
for example, I have a list of dictionary keys as such:

```
dict_keys(['1.', '1.1', '1.2', '1.2.1', '1.2.2', '1.2.2(a)', '1.2.2(b)', '1.2.2(c)', '1.2.2(d)', '1.2.3', '1.2.4', '1.2.5', '1.2.6', '1.2.7', '1.2.8', '1.2.9', '1.2.10', '1.2.11', '2.', '2.1', '3.', '3.1', '3.1.1', '3.1.2', '3.2', '3.3', '3.4', '3.5', '3.5.1', '3.5.2', '3.5.2(a)', '3.5.2(b)', '3.5.2(c)', '3.6', '3.7', '3.8', '3.9', '3.9.1', '3.9.2', '3.9.3', '3.10', '3.11', '3.11.1', '3.11.2', '4.', '4.1', '4.1.1', '4.1.2', '4.1.3', '4.1.4', '4.1.5', '4.1.6', '4.1.7', '4.1.8', '4.1.9', '4.1.10', '4.2', '5.', '5.1', '5.1.1', '5.1.2', '5.1.3', '5.1.4', '5.1.4(a)', '5.1.4(b)', '5.1.4(c)', '5.1.4(d)', '5.1.4(e)', '5.1.4(f)', '5.1.4(g)', '5.1.4(h)', '5.1.4(i)', '5.1.4(j)', '5.1.4(k)', '5.2', '5.3', '5.4', '6.', '6.1', '6.2', '7.', '7.1', '7.2', '7.3', '7.3.1', '7.3.2', '7.3.3', '7.4', '7.5', '7.6', '7.6.1', '7.6.2', '7.6.3', '7.6.4', '8.', '8.1', '8.2', '8.2.1', '8.2.2', '8.2.3', '8.2.4', '8.2.5', '8.2.6', '8.2.7', '8.3', '8.3.1', '8.3.2', '8.3.3', '8.3.4', '8.3.5', '8.3.6', '8.4', '9.', '9.1', '9.1.1', '9.1.2', '9.2', '9.3', '9.4', '9.5', '10.', '10.1', '10.2', '10.3', '10.4', '11.', '11.1', '11.2', '11.2.1', '11.2.2', '11.2.3', '11.3', '11.4', '11.5', '11.6', '11.7', '11.8', '11.9', '11.10', '12.', '12.1', '12.2', '12.2.1', '12.2.2', '12.3', '12.4', '12.4.1', '12.4.2', '12.4.3', '12.5', '12.6', '12.7', '12.8', '12.9', '12.10', '12.11', '13.', '13.1', '13.2', '13.3', '13.3.1', '13.3.2', '13.3.3', '13.3.4', '13.4', '13.4.1', '13.4.2', '13.4.3', '14.', '14.1', '14.2', '14.3', '15.', '15.1', '15.2', '15.2.1', '15.2.2', '15.2.3', '15.2.4', '16.', '16.1', '16.2', '16.3', '16.4', '16.5', '16.6', '16.7', '16.7.1', '16.7.2', '17.', '17.1', '17.1.1', '17.1.2', '17.1.3', '17.1.4', '17.2', '17.2.1', '17.2.2', '17.2.3', '17.2.4', '17.3', '17.4', '17.4.1', '17.4.2', '17.5', '17.5.1', '17.5.2', '17.5.3', '18.', '18.1', '18.2', '18.2.1', '18.2.1(a)', '18.2.1(b)', '18.2.1(c)', '18.2.2', '18.2.3', '18.2.4', '18.2.5', '18.2.5(a)', '18.2.5(b)', '18.2.6', '18.2.7', '19.', '19.1', '19.2', '19.3', '19.4', '20.', '21.', '21.1', '21.2', '21.3', '21.4', '22.', '22.1', '22.1.1', '22.1.2', '22.1.3', '22.1.4', '22.2', '22.2.1', '22.2.2', '22.3', '22.4', '22.5', '22.6', '22.6.1', '22.6.2', '22.7', '23.', '23.1', '23.1.1', '23.1.1(a)', '23.1.1(b)', '23.1.1(c)', '23.1.2', '23.1.3', '23.1.3(a)', '23.1.3(b)', '23.1.4', '23.2', '23.2.1', '23.2.2', '23.3', '23.4', '23.5', '24.', '24.1', '24.1.1', '24.1.2', '24.1.3', '24.1.4', '24.1.5', '24.1.6', '24.2', '24.3', '25.', '25.1', '25.1.1', '25.1.2', '25.1.3', '25.1.4', '25.1.5', '25.1.6', '25.2', '25.2.1', '25.2.2', '25.2.3', '25.2.4', '25.2.5', '25.3', '26.', '27.', '27.1', '27.2', '27.2.1', '27.2.2', '27.2.3', '27.3', '28.', '28.1', '28.2', '28.2.1', '28.2.2', '28.2.3', '28.2.4', '28.2.5', '28.3', '29.', '29.1', '29.1.1', '29.1.2', '29.1.3', '29.2', '30.', '30.1', '30.2', '30.2.1', '30.2.2', '30.2.3', '30.3', '30.4', '31.', '31.1', '31.2', '31.3', '31.4', '31.5', '31.5.1', '31.5.2', '31.6', '31.7', '31.8', '31.8.1', '31.8.2', '31.8.3', '31.9', '31.10', '31.11'])
```

in this, if I have something referred in key 3.1, I also want to extract the data for keys 3.1.1 and 3.1.2(child keys). so for this I used str.startwith() method which fails in cases as such.
It will not only return me the child clauses but also other clauses like 3.10, 3.11... which also start with 3.1, so this will result in some false positives and leakages.

The caveat however being that I don't know for sure that what numbering system will the user be using in the agreement.
for example:
it could be anything like:

```
['(1.)', '(1.)a.', '(2.)'] or ['1.', '1.1.', '1.1.1.', '1.1.1.a',] or ['1.', '1.1', '1.1.1', '1.1.1a']
```

so I'm trying to figure out a function using which I can cover all these ways.
How can I do that?
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Use `startswith('3.1.')`.

Comment: So by "dictionary", you do not mean Python's `dict` class, right?

Comment: @Ava, that does sound good but in that case I wont be getting the actual key and what about the case with '1.2.2(a)', if I use '1.2.2.', I'll get no keys at all.

Comment: @phipsgabler, yes I meant dict class in python.

Comment: But there is no dict. You gave a list. Probably you want a trie, with custom splitting, though.

Comment: @phipsgabler, what I've attached is a list of keys in the dict.
the values we're irrelevant to attach here.
btw you're right about using trie, but I actually need to use dictionary as the values corresponding to it store the text from that clause. 
so maybe I'll have to create a trie just for this specific use case.
I was trying to find patch which could help me in the current situation, since studying and implementing trie in a day won't be feasible. Though thanks for the help, I appreciate it. :D

Comment: @Ava, I'll be getting 1.2.2 as the key from a different method, so I'll be needing 1.2.2, 1.2.2(a) and so on. Using 1.2. will also return 1.2.3, 1.2.4 and so on. I'm trying to reduce the noise.
Maybe there is no one way to do it. I'll have to put in checks based on the next key. And that's what I can't solve, how to put those checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_subsequent_keys(key):
    subsequent_keys = []
    total_keys = structure.keys()
    try:
        if key[-1] == '.' or key[-1] == ')':
            if key in total_keys:
                pass
            elif key[:-1] in total_keys:
                subsequent_keys.append(key[:-1])
            subsequent_keys += [x for x in total_keys if x.startswith(key)]
        else:
            key_pat = fr"({key}[a-z]+)"
            subsequent_keys.append(key)
            subsequent_keys += [x for x in total_keys if x.startswith(key + '.')]
            subsequent_keys += [x for x in total_keys if x.startswith(key + '(')]
            subsequent_keys += re.findall(key_pat, '   '.join(total_keys))
    except Exception as exception:
        logger.debug(exception)
    finally:
        return subsequent_keys
```

So I used this way to cover all the possible cases.
The problem with my use case is that I don't really have a definite way by which the user numbers the clauses in the agreement. Hence I needed a generic function to cover all ground. Also, thanks to Ava and Hayley for their help! :D

Answer (score 0):

You're much more familiar with your dataset and how robust you need to be, but I set that set of `dict_keys` to `keys` and used the following:

```
if key.count('.') < 2:
    child_keys = [k for k in keys if k.startswith(key + '.')]
else:
    child_keys = [k for k in keys if k.startswith(key + '(')]
```

If `key = '1.2.2'`, then `child_keys = ['1.2.2(a)', '1.2.2(b)', '1.2.2(c)', '1.2.2(d)']`. If `key = '3.1'`, then `child_keys = ['3.1.1', '3.1.2']`.

Comment: Thanks @Hayley, this thing struck me too based on my discussion with @Ava.
I can perhaps use a few of these conditions, combined with a regex to match with the cases such as `1.1.1a` when the key is '1.1.1' and that should suffice.
Let me try this and get back to you. :D